# Getting error while saving zip file on C drive

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, zlib, fs

I've used the following code (found in SO).I want to send zip file(very simple zip file 1.5mb) and save it on my C drive with the following code. 
I use postman with binary and upload zip file and send it to localhost:3012

```
ar express = require('express');
var zlib = require('zlib');
var fs = require('fs');
var app = express();

app.post('/', function (req, res) {
    var writeStream = fs.createWriteStream('C://', {flags: 'w'});
    req.pipe(zlib.createInflate()).pipe(writeStream);
    res.send("Success to save zip");
});

var server = app.listen(3012, function () {
        console.log("server is listening to port" + 3012)
    }
)
```

**The error is**

```
events.js:85
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
            ^
Error: EPERM, open 'C:\'
    at Error (native)
```

I use webstorm as admin, any idea what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Is this the same trying to write to all folders or just when you try to write to c:\ ?

Comment: @CodeUniquely- Do you want  my to do additional test ,please let me know what to change with code and I'll do it ASAP :) im stuck with this almost a day to make it work

Comment: I was asking if you tried writing the ZIP file into another folder that you have created (such as the folder in which you run your project code) because it might be an issue with you trying to write to the ROOT of your drive. so just trying something like fs.createWriteStream('C://some path//your folder//'may have a different effect.

Comment: @CodeUniquely -I've try it to specific folder and I got the same error ,any idea what it can be?do I use the code currently?Thanks in advance!

Comment: @CodeUniquely- I try to put createWriteStream('C://TestZIP//test', {flags: 'w'}); the TestZip file is folder which I've created in advance and when I run it I saw inside the TestZip folder empty file (0KB)which is called test...Do I use the code correct ? I've update the post with the all code...

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the write stream as this:

```
 var writeStream = fs.createWriteStream('C://', {flags: 'w', mode: 0666});
```

It seems you don't have permission while executing the save.

More https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createwritestream_path_options

Comment: Thanks Diogo ,I try it now and I got the same error :( Do I need to do something in addition?

Comment: No that should work however this is permissions error. I assume you are creating an empty zip (if you are not make sure you don't have the file open in any other software) and are you running the IDE with Administrator account or with you account that has administrator rights?

Comment: Also writing in the root of C: is usually tricky, try to write in Documents folder first as permission wise it is more lenient

Comment: I've run the IDE with admin rights...to write to document folder is not the same since its under C drive also?

Comment: No usually writing in the root isn't the same i had a similar problem and i solved it by changing folders

Comment: Thanks A lot voted up! The new folder was read-only :(,Now when I run the application I got the following error events.js:85
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
            ^
Error: incorrect header check
    at Zlib._handle.onerror (zlib.js:366:17)

Comment: are you trying do decompress the file?

Comment: HI Again ,this is all my code (which I provided in the post) Im failry new to to this topic,Should I do something in addition?if yes can you add it to your answer and i'll try it ASAP

Comment: i will try to have a look at the library and your code later if i have time :)